# jQuery value pass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to re-style the `select` `option`, 
however the option's value doesn't pass to the new  class created by jQuery.
Thus, I am unable to get the right result. 
The correct result is when I click US, it shows Austin, when click Germany shows Berlin

Here is the code,
http://jsfiddle.net/xvDbv/1/

Should change to something like

```
   text: $this.children('option','value').eq(i).text()?
```

could someone help with the `VALUE` pass problem?

Many thanks in adv

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want the submenus to display based on the selected option's value, right?

Comment: yes, but the value is not passing... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you never call the `countrySelectChanged` function when you build you pseudo select. Add a call to it in the function:

```
$listItems.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide(); /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
    countrySelectChanged();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xvDbv/5/)**

Comment: I wrote the exact same `countrySelectChanged` code (except without checks or var statements)  and didn't realize it was already in the fiddle.. +1

Comment: I just realized a problem is that, once the list is long, the option box is not scrollable, http://jsfiddle.net/xvDbv/6/, do I need a plugin ? thanks

Comment: I see the browser scroll bar show up when it's long. Were you looking for a scroll bar on the option box instead?

Comment: No, never thought about this part! but I am looking for an option now, any suggestions? Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I added the `on` listener to the `li`.

```
    $('<li />', {
        text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
        rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
    }).on("click", function(){
        $(".hide").hide();
        $("#" + $(this).text().toLowerCase() + "-select").show();
    }).appendTo($list);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/xvDbv/7/)